# if i define something in a class, how do i call in within the class?

Tags: php

i have something like

```
 define("__ROOT_PATH__", "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/admin");
```

within a class. how do i call it from within functions is it with a cologn? i tried looking it up on google but nothing.

thanks

Answer (score 11):

The function [`define()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) is intended for global constants, so you just use the string `__ROOT_PATH__` (I would recommend using another naming scheme, though. Constants starting with two underscores are reserved by PHP for their [magic constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php))

```
define('__ROOT_PATH__', 'Constant String');
echo __ROOT_PATH__;
```

If you want to declare a class constant, use the [const keyword](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php):

```
class Test {
    const ROOT_PATH = 'Constant string';
}
echo Test::ROOT_PATH;
```

There is one problem though: The class constants are evaluated while your script is being parsed, so you cannot use other variables within these constants (so your example will not work). Using `define()` works, as it is treated like any other function and the constant value can be defined dynamically.

**EDIT**:

As [PCheese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61274/pcheese) pointed out, you can access class constants using the keyword `self`, instead of the class name from within the class:

```
class Test {
    const ROOT_PATH = 'Constant string';
    public function foo() {
        echo self::ROOT_PATH;
    }
}
# You must use the class' name outside its scope:
echo Test::ROOT_PATH;
```

Comment: I think I like your answer better, it's more concise: I would simply add that within a function of the Test class, you can refer to constants with `self::ROOT_PATH`

Answer (score 3):

Using `define` will define the constant globally, so just refer to it directly in your code:

```
echo __ROOT_PATH__;
```

If you want to scope a constant to a class, you need to declare it differently. However, this syntax will not let you declare it dynamically as you did above, using `$_SERVER`.

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    const MY_CONST = "foo";
    public function showConstant() {
        echo self::MY_CONST;
    }
}

// Example:
echo MyClass::MY_CONST;
$c = new MyClass();
$c->showConstant();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the name of the constant.

i.e.

```
  echo "Root path is " . __ROOT_PATH__;
```